# How do I get rid of these insects that are in all of my planters?

Tags: diagnosis, pest-control, container-gardening

How do I get rid of these insects that are in all of my planters? 
I find them only to be in the dirt and not on the plants.
To me they look spider mites, but they did not die out when I applied [***Bayer Advanced™*** 3-In-1 Insect, Disease & Mite Control](http://www.bayeradvanced.com/insects-pests/products/3-in-1-insect-disease-mite-control) on them directly, they just scampered on.
I'll add pics once I get home so you can come to your better judgments.

Comment: Are you sure they are damaging your plants? Also, bayer advanced doesn't always kill immediately. The insecticide used in that product is [Imidacloprid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imidacloprid), a neurotoxin, so it won't kill on contact like some insecticides. The miticide used is [Tau-Fluvalinate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluvalinate), which is a different neorotoxin affecting sodium channels in mites. Don't expect immediate results.

Comment: Thanks for the info regarding the product im using. I dont want to wait for it to get to that point

Comment: Chances are good that these are fungus gnats.  They do not harm the plant and can be controlled by good cultural practices. See http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3306/indoor-garden-built-now-little-flies/3314#3314

Comment: I tried to get some pics last night but they’re too small for  me to focus on. so I’ll explain what I see, they basically look like little clear/silvery sesame seeds with no wings.

Answer (score 2):

I like to give the recommended dose of diluted Neem oil weekly to keep off the insects, it has worked wonders here in Florida. As Kevinsky also commented, it is possible they are fungus nats and wont harm the plants in any way.

Comment: @ Apoc Yes I added neem oil to my next shopping list thanks. As for the fungus gnats although they arent damaging the plants just anoying, they lay lots of eggs in the dirt and when they hatch they feed on the roothair a slow downward spiral for plants.

Comment: BTW do I have to dilute "Bayer Advanced Ready-to-Use Natria Neem Oil"?